# Iterator behaves well when subclassing from list, but not from deque - Python

Tags: python, list, inheritance, iterator, deque

I would like to create a "circular list" object: one through which I could iterate, cyclically, forever. To that effect, I attempted to subclass the `list` class as such:

```
from itertools import cycle 

class Circle(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iter__(self):
        sup_iter = super().__iter__()
        return cycle(sup_iter)
```

And, indeed, it works wonderfully (to an extent. It's not possible to convert it back to a `list`, as some answers have pointed out). If, however, I attempt to base my class on the `deque` class, I can seemingly no longer
call my `str` or `repr` on my objects
as doing so makes the python interpreter freeze, and the process eventually gets killed. Bear in mind that none of it happens when the class inherits from `list`.

I am at a loss, can anyone help shed some light into what's going on?

Comment: `list(Circle([1,2,3]))` will probably freeze your interpreter too.  Confirm?

Comment: When I wrote this post, I was under the wrongful impression it didn't, but it does indeed. I have since edited the post not to confuse future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list repr in CPython is defined here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.3/Objects/listobject.c#L361-L415

The important point is that this loop uses

```
for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(v); ++i) { ...
```

and you don't override the size of the object at all, so a `Circle([1,2,3])` still has 3 elements as far as the list repr is concerned. The loop does a repr on each element, and then finishes.

The deque repr in CPython is defined here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.3/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L1376-L1404

The important point is that this code uses

```
aslist = PySequence_List(deque);
```

i.e. it first represents the deque as a list, which for your `Circle` class will be an infinite loop, eventually consuming all memory available and appearing to freeze your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Both converting them to lists and calling repr ([which will try to convert it to a list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L1389) in the process of building a repr string) will attempt to iterate over the deque.

But you've "broken" this by making iteration never end.

One might say that the code that does this (eventually, [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L862)) could look at the length of the object (if it had one, not all would) and stop after that many elements, but it does not:

```
    /* Run iterator to exhaustion. */
    for (;;) {
        PyObject *item = iternext(it);
        ...
```

IMO, you're better off leaving `__iter__` as-is and using `cycle(your_circle)` where you want to iterate over your circular list.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't call `list` on an infinite iterator.  The definition of `list` on an iterator is that it keeps on reading elements until the iterator tells it there are no more.

Do you know about `itertools.cycle`?